# Django download static file using html button

Tags: django

I am creating a site with Django where users can gather data from diffrent websites, review it, save it to database and download all the data as a file(txt or csv). I have this problem where i can't create a href link (`{% static 'files/filename' %}`) to specific static file that users can download.

When i try to add href attribute to a link and click it i get this error where instead of for example this: 
`<a id="download" href="/static/file/Shrek_reviews.txt" download=""></a>`

i get this:

`<a id="download" href="/static/file/%22%20%2B%20btn_n%20%2B%20%22_reviews.txt" download=""></a>`

can someone tell how can i parse file name to `{% static 'file/file_name' %}` so it can work propertly ?

Below is my view function and ajax function that creates href attribute and download file. Thanks in advance for Your help

**ajax function**

```
 $('button').click(function(){
            var btn_t = $(this).text();
            var btn_n = $(this).attr('name');
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "{% url 'proces:films_data' %}",
              data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                btn_text:btn_t,
                btn_name:btn_n,
              },
              success: function(data){
                if(btn_t == 'txt') {
                    $("#download").attr("href", "{% static 'file/" + btn_n + "_reviews.txt' %}");
                } else {
                    $("#download").attr("href", "{% static 'file/" + btn_n + "_reviews.csv' %}");
                }
                $('#download').trigger('click');
              }
            });
        });
```

**View function**

```
def films_data(request):
db_film_data = Films.objects.all()

if request.method == "POST":
    data = {}
    db_selected_film = Films.objects.get(title=request.POST['btn_name'])
    db_film_reviews = Reviews.objects.filter(film_id=db_selected_film).all()
    file_path = os.getcwd() + '/static/file/' + db_selected_film.title + "_reviews.txt"

    if request.POST['btn_text'] == 'txt':
        with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write("Film title: " + db_selected_film.title + '\n\n')
            for rev in db_film_reviews:
                file.write("Review title: " + rev.title + "\n")
                file.write("Review Author: " + rev.author + "\n")
                file.write("Review:\n" + rev.review + "\n")
                file.write("This review was helpful for " + rev.helpful + " users\n\n")

    return JsonResponse(data)
return render(request, 'proces/films.html', {'films': db_film_data})
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't possibly work. Django template tags are rendered on the server, well before the JS can execute on the browser. There is no way to include a JS variable in a Django template tag.

You should do the concatenation entirely in JS.

```
var static = "{{ STATIC_URL }}"
if(btn_t == 'txt') {
    $("#download").attr("href", "file/" + btn_n + "_reviews.txt");
} else {
    $("#download").attr("href", "file/" + btn_n + "_reviews.csv");
}
```

Although a better approach would be to avoid writing the file to the static directory at all; instead, return the file contents in the Ajax response and allow downloading in the JS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer, i have manage to work this around by removing download attribute from link and adding it in JS function. I have also change the way im saving files by giving it a static file name and then change the name of downloaded file when i click on link i html.

Here is my new JS script:

```
$('button').click(function(){
            var btn_t = $(this).text();
            var btn_n = $(this).attr('name');
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "{% url 'proces:films_data' %}",
              data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                btn_text:btn_t,
                btn_name:btn_n,
              },
              success: function(data){
                if(btn_t == 'txt') {
                    $("#download").attr("href", "{% static 'file/film_reviews.txt' %}");
                    $('#download').attr('download', btn_n + "_reviews.txt");
                } else {
                    $("#download").attr("href", "{% static 'file/film_reviews.csv' %}");
                    $('#download').attr('download', btn_n + "film_reviews.csv");
                }
                document.getElementById("download").click()
              }
            });
        });
```

Now it works good